# How do I assign the output of a command to a variable?

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to assign a value to a variable, that value which we get in terminal by writing any command?

Example command: `sensors`

From that we get CPU temperature. How can I assign this value to a `temp_cpu` variable?

Comment: This question is more suited to [su] or to [unix.se]. Try `temp_cpu=$(sensors)` (this will turn newlines to spaces, though). You can use `grep` to filter the specific info you need, too.

Comment: @edwin why is the question not so suitable for this place?

Comment: @Tshepang, this question is not specific to Ubuntu, it's just about the *Unix-like* shell. Thus, [unix.se].

Comment: Did the policy/general opinion change? I thought this site welcomed questions that are not necessarily specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: @edwin The comments are old so you're likely aware of this, but *this is on-topic*, per [the help](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), [Are non-Ubuntu-spefic questions allowed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14663), [Are “not only Ubuntu-specific” questions on-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14523), [How do we tell if a question belongs here, or rather at stackoverflow/superuser?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/47), [Are bash/shell scripting questions on topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13807) ([related](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/))

Answer (score 40):

Yes, you use `my_var=$(some_command)`. For example:

```
$ foo=$(date)
$ echo $foo
Mon Jul 22 18:10:24 CLT 2013
```

Or for your specific example, using `sed` and `grep` to get at the specific data you want:

```
$ cpu_temp=$(sensors acpitz-virtual-0 | grep '^temp1:' | sed 's/^temp1: *//;s/ .*//')
$ echo $cpu_temp
+39.0°C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also store the value of command as follows:

```
variableName=`command`
$variableName
```

For example:

```
currentDirectory=`pwd`
$currentDirectory
```

Comment: think code formatting on your example got lost.

Comment: This works but this type of substitution cannot be nested, so [the other option](https://askubuntu.com/a/323167/250300) is preferred. @bac0n I’ve fixed the formatting problem.