# Can't assign function result to a variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Follow by

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809899/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-function-to-a-variable-using-bash and 
[How do I assign the output of a command to a variable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323162/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-variable)

I wrote

```
function getos(){
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/27776822/1637673
    case "$(uname -s)" in
       Darwin)
         OS='mac'
         ;;
       Linux)
         OS='linux'
         ;;
       CYGWIN*|MINGW32*|MSYS*)
         OS='win'
         ;;
       # Add here more strings to compare
       # See correspondence table at the bottom of this answer
       *)
         OS='other'
         ;;
    esac
    echo $OS
}


echo $(getos)

OS=${getos}
echo ${OS} # show nothing
echo $OS   # show nothing
echo $(OS) # line 36
```

But 
`bash common.sh` got

```
linux


common.sh: line 36: OS: command not found
```

What's the problem ??

Comment: If you edit the answer in the source, people will stare at it, searching for the error - like me. Only after reading the answer and investigating your edit history (which beginners can't do, AFAIK), I can see, what the original question was. It doesn't make sense to remove the part, which triggered the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` tries to run the command `OS` and fails because

```
$(OS)
```

is [Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) whereas

```
${OS} # or
$OS
```

is [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#simple_usage).

The correct way to print the content of variable `OS` is `echo $OS`.

I suppose you however want to *run* your function, that assigns a value to your variable `OS`, and then print its content if not done by the function already:

```
getos
echo $OS
```

Comment: `echo ${OS}` and `echo $OS`  show nothing

Comment: My function return `echo $OS` ,  I want to set the return result to another variable ,  here just with same name OS .

Comment: I think the issue is that `OS=${getos}` expects `getos` to be a *variable*, not a function - they're effectively different namespaces (i.e. unless you have a *variable* with the same name, `${getos}` is empty)

Comment: Oh, I am so careless.  I looked `{` as `(` . Should be `OS=$(getos)` .

Answer (score 4):

The underlying issue is that `OS=${getos}` expects `getos` to be a *variable*, not a function (it is a parameter expansion rather than a command substitution) - they're effectively different namespaces:

```
$ function foo() { echo foo; }
$ foo
foo
$ echo ${foo}

$
```

(i.e. **variable** `foo` is empty); whereas

```
$ foo=bar
$
$ foo
foo
$ echo ${foo}
bar
```

If you want `OS` to be a synonym for `getos`, you can use an *alias*:

```
alias OS='getos'
```

(although if you're using this in a script, be aware that alias expansion is only enabled in by default in interactive shells).

*TL;DR: parentheses and braces are NOT interchangeable*