# Creating a Function That Sets a Variable to a Random Integer

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am writing a shell script on my Linux machine, and I'm trying to figure out a good way to write a function that I could call that would set a variable, let's call it $variable, to a random number between 1 and 466,550.  Of course I could write;

```
shuf -i 1-466550 -n 1
```

And it'll do the trick, but how could I write this in a function to have it set my variable, $variable, to that random number (until the function is called again, at which case it picks another random integer from 1-466,550)?

Comment: Are you asking [How do I assign the output of a command to a variable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323162/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend reading through [a bash scripting guide](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20learn%20bash%20scripting).
I usually recommend [Bash Scripting for Beginners](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) and [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), though they have not been updated for a couple of years...

With that said, here's an example of how it could be done.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

generate_random() {
    shuf -i 1-466550 -n 1
}

variable="$(generate_random)"
echo "random number: ${variable}"
variable="$(generate_random)"
echo "another random number: ${variable}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and for the links!

Answer (score 0):

Generating a random number with bash $RANDOM variable:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

f(){
    echo $(((RANDOM * RANDOM) % 466550 + 1))
}
x=$(f)
echo $x
```